# How can I call function from another function?

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, google-analytics

I am having two different functions for google analytics. I am trying to call a function from another function. I am getting an error that says `TypeError: this is undefined`. I cannot understand why?

```
handleAccounts = (response) => {
  var details = response.result.items;
  console.log(response);
  this.setState({
    info: details
  });
  details.map(function(x) {
    gapi.client.analytics.management.webproperties
      .list({accountId: x})
      .then(this.handleProperties.bind(this)); //This is the line where I am getting the Error.
  });
}

handleProperties = (response) => {
  // Handles the response from the webproperties list method.
  if (response.result.items && response.result.items.length) {
    // Get the first Google Analytics account
    var firstAccountId = response.result.items[0].accountId;

    // Get the first property ID
    var firstPropertyId = response.result.items[0].id;

    // Query for Views (Profiles).
    //queryProfiles(firstAccountId, firstPropertyId);
    console.log(response);
  } else {
    console.log('No properties found for this user.');
  }
}
```

Comment: try changing `details.map(function(x){` to `details.map(x => {`

Comment: you have to bind "this" to your arrow function, arrow functions don't automatically assume "this"

Comment: It's working now. Thanx a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these functions are being called from within a component then you need to `bind` them within the components `constructor` or `componentDidMount`. Binding is necessary to make 'this' work in the callback as class methods aren't bound by default in React.